# Why i am getting nullpointer exception at this.getWritableDatabase();, android?

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception

Exception occurs at  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Providing with my databasehandler  class

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "chat";

    // Contacts table name
    private static final String TABLE_CHAT = "chat_history";

    // Contacts Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_TT = "tt";
    private static final String KEY_TYPE = "type";
    private static final String KEY_MSG = "message";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CHAT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CHAT + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_TT + " TEXT," + KEY_TYPE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_MSG + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CHAT_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CHAT);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    // Adding new contact

    public void addContact(String tt, String type, String msg) {
       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        System.out.println("tt "+tt);
        System.out.println("msg "+msg);
        System.out.println("type "+type);
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_TT, tt); // Contact Name
        values.put(KEY_TYPE, type); // Contact Phone Number
        values.put(KEY_MSG, msg);

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_CHAT, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    // Getting All Contacts
    public List<ChatHistory> getAllContacts(String T) {
        List<ChatHistory> contactList = new ArrayList<ChatHistory>();
        // Select All Query
        System.out.println("database T$$$$$$$$$$$"+T);

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CHAT + " WHERE "+ KEY_TT+"="+"'"+T+"'";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                ChatHistory chatHistory = new ChatHistory();
            chatHistory.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                chatHistory.settt(cursor.getString(1));
            chatHistory.settype(cursor.getString(2));
            chatHistory.setmsg(cursor.getString(3));
                // Adding contact to list
                contactList.add(chatHistory);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return contactList;
    }
}
```

I keep getting exception on this line
 SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

Its nullpointer exception..
I am not able to solve the issue.
Please suggest a solution
It is some error of context 
How to resolve it?

Comment: Maybe the database name is not complete. Try to change do "chat.dat" (with the file ending)..does it solve the problem?

Comment: just to clarify... where's your getWritableDatabase() method located?

Comment: He/she is referring to [SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getWritableDatabase()). Have you tried to obtain the stacktrace of the NullPointerException you are getting? `try { /*problem code*/ } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); /*or you can log the stacktrace*/ }`

Comment: Please join the full stack trace please.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your database has not been created because you are executing wrong query. You forgot to add a semi-colon at end.

What your are doing is :

```
String CREATE_CHAT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CHAT + "("
        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_TT + " TEXT," + KEY_TYPE + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_MSG + " TEXT" + ")";
```

use this instead

```
String CREATE_CHAT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CHAT + "("
        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_TT + " TEXT," + KEY_TYPE + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_MSG + " TEXT" + ");";
```

Then uninstall your app and try again.

Comment: that is not the issue bt still thnx

Answer (score 1):

Two possible cause of this problem, both of them are mainly coming because of in-proper usage of code inside onCreate or onUpgrade ..

1) validate your SQL queries in both methods onCreate and onUpgrade  (you could run and validate your written queries using any a dummy test sqlite database via [SQLiteBrowser](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/releases)

2) make sure you're using the same way as below (NOT to use the external SQLiteDatabase object if you have, just use the inner and the passed one)

```
public class SqliteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    SQLiteDatabase dbHelper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
       db.execSQL("YOUR CREATE QUERY"); //don't use dbHelper here 
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db) {
       db.execSQL("YOUR UPGRADE QUERY"); //don't use dbHelper here
    }

    public void open() throws SQLExceptions {
      dbHelper = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close(){
      dbHelper.close();
    }

    public long insert(...){
      open();
      //your access is here through dbHelper
      close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Fragment initialize the context inside `onCreate View` as

```
DbProgram dbProgram;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
        **dbProgram = new DbProgram(getActivity());** // Context here solves your problem............
        return view;
    }
```

If you are not using Fragment initialize the `context` inside `onCreate` method

```
MarketAppDbAdapter db;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        **db = new MarketAppDbAdapter(MainActivity.this);**// Your problem solves here...........
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do the query related work inside your DatabaseHandler class. Keep it only for open, close, upgrade, create related work. Use the synchronized method call with explicit exception thrown.

As a clue try like this:

```
    /**
     * open the db
     * @return this
     * @throws SQLException
     * return type: DatabaseHandler
     */
    public synchronized DatabaseHandler open() throws SQLException 
    {
        if(db == null || !db.isOpen())
            this.db = getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }
```

Then for your rawquery define the method returning Cursor object:

```
public synchronized Cursor rawQuery(String sql, String[] args) throws SQLException{
        if(db == null || !db.isOpen())
            this.open();
        return db.rawQuery(sql, args);
    }
```

Then in your class where you want to perform the select query related work do:

```
protected DatabaseHandler dbHandler;
dbHandler = DatabaseHandler.getInstance(activity.getApplicationContext());
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CHAT + " WHERE "+ KEY_TT+"="+"'"+T+"'";
Cursor r = dbHandler.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
```

The relevant looping code will come below it.

Hope it will help!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating a database object in addContact method, create it in onCreate method of DatabaseHandler class,

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    SQLiteDatabase db ;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //write you code here..
         this.db=db;

        }


}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think and keep in mind I'm not an expert that you are using the SQLiteopenhelper class for more than it it is interned for.  I believe it should only be extended for "A helper class to manage database creation and version management."
So I suggest creating a separate class that uses your databaseshandler class to get your writable database and put methods for your database manipulation there.
Along the same lines you can make the suggested class but put your current class inside of it as an inner class.  (Just be sure to move the CRUD methods to the new clas

Comment: it does not answer the question ;)